# Logging into Plone site with credentials passed through HTTP

Tags: single-sign-on, plone-4.x

I am using Plone 4.3.3 and am fairly new to Plone development. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

I have another site which is going to redirect to my Plone site. In the http url line the redirects to the Plone site I would like to pass a username whereas Plone site should automatically log the user with that username in without asking any credentials like password. I do not care about safety or encryption at this point. How would you achieve that? (I guess I need somehow to modify that existing login view, but how do I do that?) Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and at the end I've developed my own [PAS](http://docs.plone.org/old-reference-manuals/pluggable_authentication_service/index.html) plugin. I've followed next steps:

1. Create a PAS plugin
2. Implement the extractCredentials method following [this example](http://docs.plone.org/old-reference-manuals/pluggable_authentication_service/credential-extraction.html)
3. Implement the authenticateCredentials method following [this example](http://docs.plone.org/old-reference-manuals/pluggable_authentication_service/credential-authentication.html)
4. Add the plugin to the develop section in the build.conf.
5. Start the Plone and open the Zope console. Go to the [acl_users folder](http://docs.plone.org/old-reference-manuals/pluggable_authentication_service/configuring-pas.html) and add your plugin to the PAS system

There are some examples [here](http://svn.plone.org/svn/collective/PASPlugins/) that you can use like templates.